# HTML for submit button does not insert data to database and redirect to URL together

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal, form-submit

I am trying to insert user data to a database and after inserting the data to the database, the form will be redirected to PayPal check out page.

I have tried hidden input fill, that field will insert data to database after submitting the form but it did not work. My code:

```
 <?php

include './config.php';

if (isset($_POST['form_submit'])) {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $query = "INSERT INTO payment (customer_id, amount, email, date) VALUES ('$customer_id', '$amount', '$email', '$date')";
    $res = $conn->query($query);
}
?>

 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
     <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="GGRGNF52LT9RW">
     <ul class="row">
         <!-- name -->
         <li class="col-sm-4">
             <label>
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" placeholder="ID" required>
             </label>
         </li>

         <!-- number -->
         <li class="col-sm-4">
             <label>
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Payment Amount" required>
             </label>
         </li>

         <!-- email -->
         <li class="col-sm-4">
             <label>
                 <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" 
                        placeholder="Paypal Email Address" required>
             </label>
         </li>
     </ul>

    <input type="hidden"  name="form_submit" >
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" 
    border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" 
    style="height:60px">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
 </form>
```

Comment: why is the form action to the **https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr**?

Answer (score 1):

*Change here*

**in php code**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Comment: please mark as verified this answer if its help for you so other can refer this answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not redirecting to PayPal, you are sending form data to PayPal that's why the data is not inserting in your DB.

You should first send data to your page:

```
<form action="currentpagename.php" method="POST">
```

After inserting data, you should redirect:

```
$res = $conn->query($query);
header("location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is you are sending all the form data to "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" URL and trying to access those data from your current page. Which will definately not work (because the form data are not available in the current page to process).

Action field in form tag represents where to send the form-data when the form is submitted.

For your case if your PHP and HTML codes are in same file (let's say `xyz.php`) then you need to provide the same file name in the action field.

For example:

```
<form action="xyz.php" method="post" target="_top">
```

This will send all the form data in the same file from where you can do `$_POST['amount']` to get those values.

Once you get the values insert in to the database and then redirect the page to Paypal checkout page.

To redirect using PHP code:

```
// header( $header, $replace, $http_response_code )
header("Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
```